# coroutineScope doesnt wait for child coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, scope, kotlin-coroutines

i try to learn coroutines in Kotlin and now i have a problem with some code i played with in the Kotlin Playground.

I have two suspend-functions. One with a delay of 3seconds. I will call both functions inside a coroutinescope. If i call getWeatherReport() in the main, i expect that it prints both messages nearly at the same time, because its said, that coroutinescopes waits for all its child-coroutines to be done with computation, and then returns.
But why does here 30 Degrees get printed immediately after 100 ms?

From the official doc: "This function returns as soon as the given block and all its children coroutines are completed."
What exactly does it mean the function returns?

```
suspend fun getWeatherReport() = coroutineScope {


launch { getTemperature() }
launch { getWind() }

}


suspend fun getTemperature(){
delay(100)
println("30 Degrees")
}

suspend fun getWind(){
delay(3000)
println("Wind by North")
}
```

This is how i call in main:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
runBlocking {

   getWeatherReport()
   }
 }
```

Comment: When I try that and put a `println` after the call to `getWeatherReport()`, it works properly. Can you please share a [mcre] illustrating your issue?

Comment: It's unclear why you expect println to be delayed beyond your `delay` duration.

Comment: @Pawel why is it unclear? If i read the documentation right getWeatherReport() should only be executed if the coroutinescope has its task done completely. But how can the coroutinescope send some information to the function if its child coroutines arent finished yet?

Comment: It is unclear because `println`s are a step of child coroutines. They are not a "return value" by any means. Your `getWeatherInformation()` currently returns a finished `Job` of `launch { getWind() }` which is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's explain `coroutineScope` with simpler (or I'd say more appropriate) case.

```kotlin
suspend fun getText() = coroutineScope {
    delay(1000)
    println("Block done")
    "Hello world"
}

suspend fun getTextWithChild() = coroutineScope {
    launch {
        delay(3000)
        println("Child done")
    }
    delay(1000)
    println("Block done")
    "Hello world"
}

suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   println(getText())
   println(getTextWithChild())
}
```

Both getText functions execute their main block and we get "Block Done" printed after a second. At this point they have their return value of "Hello World" ready.

Now we can notice the difference in behavior that "This function returns as soon as the given block and all its children coroutines are completed".

In first case it's straightforward - since there are no children it returns immediately  and `main` can print "Hello world".

In second case - despite finishing the block `coroutineScope` is not done yet. It still has an active child job that was launched within it - only after additional 2000 ms pass we see "Child done" printed which means it's finished and the scope can return. Finally we see "Hello world" printed from `main`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i fully understood the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two independent coroutines.

Put both suspend functions in the same launch and they will wait for one another.

```
coroutineScope.launch { 
    getTemperature() 
    getWind()
}
```

As mentioned in the comments. If you have two launch blocks you have no guarantee that your code will execute sequentially.

Comment: It should be said, that they will execute sequentially, getTemperature() will execute first, and then getWind()